# Why can't I use values of nodes I retrieve by using exsl:node-set/set:distinct in an XPath-Expression?

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, xerces, xalan

In a xslt-stylesheet I'm using the methods `exsl:node-set` and `set:distinct` to access and filter unique nodes from a variable that contains a result tree fragment.
I can write the values of these nodes into my output file, example:

```
<xsl:variable name="myNodes">
  <xsl:call-template name="getNodes"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(exsl:node-set($myNodes)/key)">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The values of the keys are written in the output, just as expected.
However, if I try to use the values in an XPath expression, it fails:

```
<xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(exsl:node-set($myNodes)/key)">
  <xsl:variable name="result" select="/tree//somenode[@key = current()]"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now, the output is empty, whereas I know that there is a "somenode" in my input-xml that should be selected by the XPath expression and it's value is not empty.

Now my question is: Why does this happen?

I'm using Java 1.6, Xerces 2.7 and Xalan 2.7.

update:
as requested, some data for the example:
xml doc contains:

```
<tree>
  <somenode key="123"/>
  <num>123</num>
  <num>0815</num>
</tree>
```

the getNodes template:

```
<xsl:template name="getNodes">
  <xsl:for-each select="/tree/num">
    <xsl:element name="key">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with some example data?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a solution and explanations of the problems in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a transformation that does something close to what you want**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
 xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="myNodes">
    <xsl:call-template name="getNodes"/>
  </xsl:variable>


  <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(exsl:node-set($myNodes)/key)">
    <xsl:variable name="result" select="$vDoc/tree//somenode[@key = current()]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$result"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="getNodes">
  <xsl:for-each select="/tree/num">
    <xsl:element name="key">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<tree>
  <somenode key="123"/>
  <num>123</num>
  <num>0815</num>
</tree>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<somenode key="123"/>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The source XML document cannot direstly be accessed inside the `<xsl:for-each>`,** because this instruction sets the current node to a node in another document -- the temporary tree created by `exsl:node-set()`.
2. **For this reason we capture the source XML document in a variable `$vDoc`.** We access the source XML document inside the `<xsl:for-each>` via this variable.
3. **The element `<somenode key="123"/>` has no text-node descendents and hence no string value**. Using `<xsl:value-of>` on it will not produce any output. This is why we use `<xsl:copy-of>` here -- it copies the complete element and we see the result.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the expression "/" would always let me access the root node of the xml document, didn't know this behaviour could be changed by working with a temporary tree.

Comment: @xor_eq: `/` *is* selecting the root node -- of your current document. The current document is made by `<xsl:for-each>` to be the temporary tree -- so `/` is selecting the root node of the temporary tree.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet does the same you want without extensions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="NumByValue" match="num" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="num[count(.|key('NumByValue',.)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="../somenode[@key=current()]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<somenode key="123" />
```

Comment: Looks a bit like the muenchian method of filtering unique elements. But my problem here is (and that's why I'm using the extension methods) that I have to compute the nodes that I'm later on extracting the nodes from. And because of that I can't use xsl:key since that's a top-level element.

Comment: @xor_eq: I'm reversing your logic. Instead of building a RTF with all `num` elements transformed to `key` elements, then converting this RTF to a node-set for iteration over those having unique string value, and then finaly output all `somenode` elements with such `@key`. Because unique values are in source, there is no need for two step process. For performance (avoiding node set comparison) you could have another key matching `somenode` elements and ussing `@key`.

Comment: @Alejandro: you're completely right, however, in this question I wrote a very simple example. And the example is also bad, as I can see now, because I didn't make it clear that those `num` values do not have to be unique. In my original code I don't have the unique values in my source, it's more like I've got every `num` element a few hundred times, so I have to extract the unique values first.

Comment: @xor_eq: You wrote: *I've got every num element a few hundred times, so I have to extract the unique values first*. Yes! And that's the reason I'm grouping `num` by value.

Comment: @Alejandro: You are, but with the help of xsl:key. I can't use this element, because those `num` elements are not in the source (that's only the case in my example), they are computed. I might as well try to create another xml-doc first, which computes all the `num` elements before I need them and then use xsl:key to group then and so on... but then I wouldn't have asked. I prefer to not having to create another xml-doc and compute the values I need on the fly. Which leaves me with the need for ext. functions because a recursive version, which I tried too, dies at a certain level of complexity

Comment: @xor_eq: No highway has one way. If you are computing this `num` elements, there could be a way to make this computed value to serve as the key. Ask another question with your input specifing the compution.

Comment: If I get the time, I'll try to do that.